# Mark package as `private` from CLI?

Tags: npm, package.json

Is there a way to quickly mark an npm package as `private` instead of manually editing the `package.json` afterward?

Something like this:

```sh
npm --set-private true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I am aware of, `npm config set <key> <value>` is used to set npm related configuration values for your `.npmrc` file. However, in order to change the values of the fields within your package.json you would have to use a CLI tool for working with JSON, something like [json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json).

You can install json by doing the following:

```
npm install -g json
```

Then for any node project that you wish to make the private field true you could do something along the lines of:

```
json -I -f package.json -e 'this.private=true'
```

or if you want to install the package locally do this instead:

```
./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f package.json -e 'this.private=true'
```

**NOTE**: For Window users please use double quotes and escape when necessary, an example of this is [here](https://github.com/trentm/json/issues/117):

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This is a great idea, and I think I can `alias` it to something quick to work with, but even though it says `json: updated "package.json" in-place`, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi David, I just tried it on my end with a dummy npm project that I created with npm init --yes and it worked for me. Can you remove the private field from the package.json and try it out again? I updated my answer to include if you wanted to run the tool by installing locally as well. The only caveat is you have to be in the base directory where your package.json is. Aliasing is great idea as well if you plan on doing this numerous times. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Nathan, thanks for the help. I created a dummy npm repo and tried it out, still no luck. I appreciate it anyway :)  

I posted my terminal results here:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187762

**BTW** I'm fine with global packages, in fact, `json` seems the type of package that I'd install globally anyway, like `nodemon` (another great thing).

Comment: Definitely, this is a perfect use case for a global module. Checkout this link: https://github.com/trentm/json/issues/117 I didn't realize you were on WIN so you may need to use double quotes and escape when necessary.

Comment: Easier way to do this without having to install `json` separately: `npx json -I -f package.json -e 'this.private=true'`

Answer (score 0):

I also found that [using Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/init/#toc-yarn-init-private-p), I can mark the package as `private` right when creating it:

```sh
yarn init --private
```

which proves to be useful for new packages.